# GNS3 won't launch in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt

I'm done with Windows. So I just installed Ubuntu 16.04. I followed the instructions on this website of how to install GNS3 onto Ubuntu 16.04 via the 3 commands in the prompt.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gns3/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gns3-gui
```

Now when I search for GNS in my apps it's not there. If I try to install again the prompt says GNS3 is up to date. What to do now?

Comment: You could try to enter `gns` and then `Tab` twice in a terminal. Or look at the content of the package with `dpkg -L gns3-gui` to find the command that starts the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

GNS3 executable is located in `/usr/bin/gns3`, so it may be launched by `gns3` command.

**Note:** older version from official Ubuntu repository has icon in *Education* category.